# nxclient crashes when trying to open a terminal from a remote client through "ssh -Y"

Tags: ssh, nomachine

I support around 150 linux machines.

I have 2 virtual machines on an ESXi server which I access via nxmachine v3 from a windows 7 box. These machines run CentOS5 with KDE and Lubuntu12.04.1 and they are the admin GUIs from which I support the 150 machines.

The linux machines which I manage are redhat4/5, CentOS5 and ubuntu 10 and 12.
Normally I contact the machines via ssh -Y.

Today I did an ssh -Y to a remote machine which is running Ubuntu 12.10 and ssh 6.0p1.

Then I tried to open an lxterminal on the remote machine which should display on my KDE desktop.
This immediately and reproducably crashed my nxclient session.

I tried again from my lubuntu system with the same effect.
I have not observed the phenomenon from other machines yet.

The message log on my KDE host shows:
Unexpected termination of nxagent because of signal: 11 Logger::log nxnode 3920
Googling for this revealed no usable answer.

Does anybody have a clue what is going on here or can give a hint how to solve the issue?

Add On:
 I asked the user at the remote machine to export his DISPLAY to my host and open an lxterminal. This worked without problems i. e. the nxclient did not crash.

Then the user tried to send me xeyes and this also killed the nxclient with the same error message found in the message log as above.

This makes me suspect that the problem is not solely connected to ssh but maybe to some library stuff.